# Rewrite certain URL in Nginx such that another app will serve it

Tags: nginx, redirect, url, directory

I have a config file for **mydomain.com** which is served with Drupal. Problem is this rewrite rule takes the control over any request:

```
if (!-e $request_filename) {
   rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?q=$1 last;
}
```

What I'd like to do, is to make **mydomain.com/about_me** to point to another app which I've written in Rails.

Currently Drupal is served with PHP CGI on port 9000. I tried adding lines to Nginx config such as:

```
location /about_me {
   proxy_pass $scheme://127.0.0.1:3000;
}
```

Thanks for suggestions.

Comment: You really should use a subdomain in cases like this.

Comment: Why dont you stick that if condition under the (or a) general location directive instead of having it globally within the server context, then?

Comment: Michael Hampton: this should work, but it's not exactly what I need. @3molo: i don't fully understand, this if - condition is a catch-all for clean urls. the other one is location ~ \.php {...} which actually passes requests to fastcgi.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create separate location blocks for the Rails and Drupal paths:

```
location /about_me {
    proxy_pass $scheme://127.0.0.1:3000;
}

location / {
    if (!-e $request_filename) {
        rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?q=$1 last;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This is definitely the way to go. It passes the /about_me to my Rails app. However I get another "You may have mistyped the address or the page may have moved.". Any idea why? Anyway, I decided that I'll go with subdomain, as it really easier and just works.  UPDATE: it really works!, one thing to check is that /about_me should be a valid URL in routes.rb!